# Creating a linked list in java is giving error, works for 3 elements but breaks on inserting the fourth

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I wanted to create a very simple linked list in `java`.

I went about it by creating three classes : a `listNode` class, a `LinkedList` class , and a `main` class.

the code for listNode class is this:

```
    public class listNode {

    int val;
    listNode next;


    listNode(int val){

        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }

}
```

The code for LinkedList class is here :

```
public class LinkedList {

    listNode head; 

    LinkedList(){
        head = null;   
    } 
    void insert( int v )
    {
        listNode t = new listNode(v);

        if(head == null)
        {
            head = t;
        }
        else
        {
            listNode traverse = head;
            while(traverse.next != null)
            {
                traverse = head.next;
            }
            traverse.next = t;
        }  
    }
    String stringList()
    {
        String out = "";     
         listNode h = this.head;
         while(h!=null)
         {
             out += h.val + " ";
             h = h.next;
         }    
        return out;
    }        
}
```

and main class :

```
public class ES {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
        l.insert(1);
        l.insert(5);
        l.insert(2);
        l.insert(7);
//        l.insert(10);
        System.out.println(l.stringList());
        System.out.println("hello");


    }

}
```

The issue is as follows : on only inserting upto 3 elements, the code works as expected. if you insert 1, 5 , 2 as an example, it will output 1 5 2 in the terminal. However, on inserting a fourth element, it gives error.

On inserting the fourth element, the program runs infinitely, without outputting everything.

Why does this peculiar behavior happen ? Why does it work for 3 elements but not for 4 ?

Note: i am working in netbeams dev environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because

```
while(traverse.next != null) {
   traverse = head.next;
}
```

is an infinite loop. You're always assigning the same value to traverse as head doea not change. If that's not meeting the criteria to exit the loop, it will run forever.

Comment: could you explain a little more, isn't traverse = head.next changing value of traverse ? It is only equal to head initially.  And why is it working for 3 but not for 4

Comment: It changes traverse to head.next. If the new traverse.next is not null, it 'changes' it again, to the very same head.next, as head didn't change in the loop. Just use a debugger and watch.

Comment: got it. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Because you always got `head.next` element in while loop.
I just changed `traverse = head.next;` to `traverse = traverse.next;` and then your code works well.